# preg_match seems to fail when i escape two forward slashes in the regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a router for a website. The fancy URL of the users page is **`u/user_name/user_id`** , where **`u`** symbolizes a user, **`user_name`** & **`user_name`** are the user name (an Alphanumeric value) & user id (a numeric value) respectively, of the user stored in the db. My regular expression to match such a uri is `/u\/[A-Za-z0-9]\/\d/`. When i pass this expression with match `u/foo/9` to `preg_match` I get a return value of 0.

But when the expression is `/u\/[A-Za-z0-9]/` (which is **not** what i desire) and is passed with match `u/foo` , `preg_match` returns a positive value of 1.

What am i doing wrong or is there a problem with my expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `'!^u/[A-Za-z0-9]+/\d+!'` a) no need for escaping when you choose a delimeter other then /  b) use the + quantifier to match more than one character

Comment: Your expression worked. Thanks a lot . But what i don't understand is that I had escaped all `/` when I used `/` as the delimiter. It should have worked right?

Comment: No. You just matched ONE char of the username and ONE digit of the user id. Would have worked fo u/m/3 but not for u/max/123

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Thanks alot guys for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed that there ca be multiple alphanumeric chars and multiple numbers within your string. Use this expression:

```
/u\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d+/
```

Comment: Thanks a loooot. This solution worked for me just as VolkerK's did. Upvotes for both of your answers. (y)